# Multiple inheritence, selecting which virtual function to call

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I have the following code sample:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a):AA(a) {};

    int AA;

    virtual int Test() 
    {
        return AA;
    };
};

class B
{
public:
    B(int b):BB(b) {};

    int BB;

    virtual int Test() 
    {
        return BB;
    };
};

class C:public A, public B
{
public:
    C(int a, int b, int c) :A(a),B(b),CC(c) {};

    int CC;
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new C(1,2,3);
    B *b = new C(1,2,3);
    C *c = new C(1,2,3);


    int x = a->Test() ; // this is 1
    int y = b->Test() ; // this is 2
//  int z = c->Test() ; // this does not compile

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the calls to a->Test() and b->Test() to be ambiguous too as the object a is a C and therefore inherits from A and B both of whom have identical Test() functions.  However, they both call the implementation which corresponds to the delcared type rather than the type that the object actually is.

Can anyone explain why these calls are not ambiguous? 
Does C++ always behave this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,a C instance is both a full A instance and a full B instance (so holds a copy of A methods & B methods)

Since a is a A* , the compiler will use the A virtual table copy that is inside of the C instance
Since b is a B* , the compiler will use the B virtual table copy that is inside of the C 
instance

you cannot use C* since the compiler will not now which Test() method of A or B you want to call (since the C class holds both A::Test & B::Test symbols)

if you implement a C::Test() method, then it will be called both instead of A::Test() & B::Test() since method is virtual for both A & B.

Comment: So is it designed behaviour that in this situation the compiler will always call the function from the declared type (assuming it is not over ridden by a descendant) i.e. can I rely on this to always happen across compilers?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Multiple_inheritance_and_thunks , it says that multiple virtual table copy is the "most common" implementation of multiple inheritance. i think if you don't use exotic compiler, this might be a reliable behaviour

Comment: And here seems to be almost the same example as they one I made up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_(programming)

Comment: @Stefan The WP page does not properly explain what a thunk is. A thunk is not a C++ function or proper asm function. It is a trivial bit of code that jumps to the right function. It does not POP/PUSH/RET.

Comment: @dweeves "_it says that multiple virtual table copy is the "most common" implementation of multiple inheritance._" it is not "most common", it is the *only* existing method.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` does not know anything about the existence of `C`.

Consider a slightly different scenario:

**foo.h**

```
class A { public: virtual void Test() {} };

void myFunction(A *a);
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

void myFunction(A *a) {
    a->Test();
}
```

You would expect this to compile, I guess?  But what if I later independently inherited from A, should that affect whether this code compiles?

Comment: I know that I am in the stage where I cannot see the wood for the trees but I am not seeing the problem. Normally I would expect your code to compile. All that is messing with my brain is the fact that Test is virtual and the call should depend on the actual type of object and not necessary the declared type but in the actual object the call is ambiguous. Clearly it is not as it is working but my brain is blocked as to why!!

Comment: Sorry I only saw part of your reply when I posted (cursed iPhone interface). If you inherited a from A and passed in a pointer to the descendant (where test is virtual) I would expect it to call the descendant's version of Test but if it also inherited Test from somewhere else how does the compiler know which to call?